# Regular Expression to replace text inside tags in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hivemind!

I am trying to edit Memsource *.mxliff files with Notepad++.
When I create a search task, both source and target lines mix up in a huge list.
But I need to make amendments only for lines inside `<target>.../<target>` tags.

For example:

```
1. <target>от 15 до 35 °C</target>
2. <target>Допустимый диапазон температур воздуха от -40 °C до +70 °C {1&gt;1)&lt;1}</target>
```

Inside these lines I need to replace all instances of degrees with a non-breaking space version:

Find: `(\d) °C`
Replace with: `$1 $2`

What is the most optimal way to do so?
Any hints would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `(\d)\s*(°C)` -> `\1 \2`

Comment: (\d)\s*°C < /target > -> \1 °C < /target >  likely with &nbsp instead of the space, and maybe gentler search of the tag, with extra \s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<target>|\G)(?:(?!target)[\s\S])*?\K(\d+)\s*(°C)(?=.*</target>)`
- Replace with: `$1&nbsp;$2`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                         # non capture group
    <target>                # opening tag
  |                         # OR
    \G                      # restart from last match position
)                           # end group
(?:(?!target)[\s\S])*?      # 0 or more any character but not "target"
\K                          # forget all we have seen until this position
(\d+)                       # group 1, 1 or more digits
\s*                         # 0 or more spaces
(°C)                        # group 2
(?=.*</target>)             # must be followed by </target>
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1              # content of group 1 (i.e. the temperature)
&nbsp;          # non breaking space
$2              # content of group 2 (i.e. °C)
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: The updated version worked like a charm, Toto! Thank you so much, you've made my day. The only update I've implemented was replacement of $nbsp; with an alt+0160 combination.

Comment: @Toto Why is the |\G (OR restart from last match position) necessary?

Comment: @John: That allows to match all temperatures from the open tag or from the last temperature.

Comment: @Toto Tyvm! I really appreciate reading your answers to so many regex questions. In fact you are the only one I can remember who answers regex questions in a sensible way. - I assume I even have understood lookaheads and behinds now, whereas I often see just links to the PCRE manual in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we'd have one `°C` in a target tag, maybe some expression similar to:

```
(<\s*target\s*>[\s\S]*?\d)\s+(°C[\s\S]*?<\s*\/target\s*>)
```

and replaced with,

```
$1$2
```

might be OK to look into.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4LYHPd/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4LYHPd/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/4LYHPd/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

Answer (score 0):

Short alternative as always ....
Find what: `(\d+) (?=°C)`
Replace all with: `$1NBSP`
Done!